# How to get the name of the current page view

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to find a way to check the view name of the current page.

```
$views_page = views_get_page_view();
if (is_object($views_page)) {
    //get the view name
}
```

I haven't found any function that gives that information. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

[views_get_page_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_page_view/7) returns a View object. The name should be stored in `$views_page->name`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a view object, call [view::get_title()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/view%3A%3Aget_title/7).

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your module file

```
function MYMODULE_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 2,
    // might not need the line below, but in any case, the last arg is the name of your module
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE'),
  );
}
```

Use below code in your MYMODULE.views.inc

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
   echo $view->name; exit;
 }
```

Relpace MYMODULE with your module name.